# EF: manual (non autogenerated) keys require ad hoc handling of new entities

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-core

In a MVVM application with EF Core as ORM I decided to model a table with a **manually inserted**, textual primary key.

This is because in this specific application I'd rather use meaningful keys instead of meaningless integer ids, at least for simple key-value tables like the table of the countries of the world.
I have something like:

```
 Id   | Description  
 -----|--------------------------
 USA  | United States of America  
 ITA  | Italy   
 etc. etc.
```

So the entity is:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my viewmodel. It's little more than a container for the ObservableCollection of Countries.  Actually it gets loaded from a repository. It's trivial and I inlcuded the entire code at the end.  It's not really relevant and I could do with just the DbContext as well. But I wanted to show all the layers to see where the solution belongs to.  Oh yes, then it contains the synchronizing code that actually offends EF Core.

```
public class CountriesViewModel
{
    //CountryRepository normally would be injected
    public CountryRepository CountryRepository { get; set; } = new CountryRepository(new AppDbContext());
    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries {get; set;}

    public CountriesViewModel()
    {
        Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        Countries.CollectionChanged += Countries_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Countries_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Country c in e.NewItems)
        {
            CountryRepository.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

In my MainWindow I just have:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:CountriesViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<DockPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

#### Problem and question

Now this doesn't work. When we try to insert a new record, in this case I do it using the automatic feature of DataGrid I get a:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to track an entity of type 'Country'
because primary key property 'Id' is null.'
```

**Each time i add a new record to the ObservableCollection I also try to add it back to the repository, that in turn adds it on the EF DbContext that doesn't accept entities with null key.**

**So what are my options here?**
One is postponing the addition of the new record till the Id has been inserted. This is not trivial as the collection handling that I've shown, but this is not the problem. The worst is that this way I would have some record that are tracked by EF (the updated and the deleted and the new with pk assigned) and some that are tracked by the view model (the new ones with the key not yet assigned).

Another is using alternate keys; I would have an integer, autogenerated primary key and the ITA,USA etc code would be an alternate key that would be used also in relations. It's not so bad from as simplicity, but I'd like a application-only solution.

#### What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a neat solution here, a pattern to be used whenever this problem arises and that plays well in the context of a MVVM/EF application.
Of course I could also look in the direction of the view events, that is force the user to insert the key before of a certain event that triggers the insertion.  I would consider it a second-class solution because it is sort of view dependent.

#### Remaining code

Just for completeness, in case that you want to run the code, here is the remaining code.

#### DbContext

(Configured for postgres)

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=WpfApp1;Username=postgres;Password=postgres");
    }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get;set; }
}
```

#### Repository

The reason why I implemented the repository for such a simple example is because I think that a possible solution may be to include the new-without-key records managment in the Repository instead of in the viewmodel.  I still hope that someone comes out with a simpler solution.

```
public class CountryRepository
{
    private AppDbContext AppDbContext { get; set; }
    public CountryRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) => AppDbContext = appDbContext;
    public IEnumerable<Country> All() => AppDbContext.Countries.ToList();
    public void Add(Country country) => AppDbContext.Add(country);

    //ususally we don't have a save here, it's in a Unit of Work; 
    //for the example purpose it's ok
    public int Save() => AppDbContext.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`? Also you should have a `CountryViewModel` just like you have a `CountriesViewModel`.

Comment: I excluded CountryViewModel just for simplicity since it doesn't add much to the example. DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOtion.None is because I have manually inserted keys, the question is about those.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest way to address the aforementioned issue in EF Core is to utilize **temporary** [value generation on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-1). In order to do that, you would need a custom [ValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.valuegenerator?view=efcore-3.1) like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration;

public class TemporaryStringValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => true; // <-- essential
    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry) => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

and fluent configuration similar to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasValueGenerator<TemporaryStringValueGenerator>()
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The potential drawbacks are:

- In pre EF Core 3.0 the generated temporary value is set onto entity instance, thus  would be visible in the UI. This has been fixed in EF Core 3.0, so now [Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#tkv)
- Even though the property looks empty (null) and is required (default for primary/alternate keys), if you don't provide explicit value, EF Core will try to issue `INSERT` command and read the "actual" value back from database similar to identity and other database generated values, which in this case will lead to non user friendly database generated runtime exception. But EF Core in general does not do validations, so this won't be so different - you have to add and validate property required rule in the corresponding layer.

Comment: That would be a great solution. I can't wait to give it a try. Unfortunately I'm using EF Core v 2.2.4 and I have to migrate it, that in turn requires a bit of testing...